# SQL Server T-SQL Replace

Tags: sql-server, case-statement

I have a case statement where I am trying to change two values from a field.

```
CASE
WHEN prod_map.Product_ID1 = 'CR'  
THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(cl.trade_day_count, 'ACT','ACTUAL'),cl.trade_day_count, 
'ACT+1', 'ACTUAL')
END,
```

so, when cl.trade_day_count contains the value 'ACT' or 'ACT+1' then change to 'ACTUAL'

Comment: The result of the 1st replace is the value you want to use as the 1st parameter on the 2nd replace function; thus you don't need cl.trade_date_count again.  Replace takes 3 parameters if I recall, your outer most is showing 4.

Comment: If we can assume `~` isn't in `cl.trade_day_count` and never will be... http://rextester.com/XYVO11480 `Replace(REPLACE(REPLACE('~'+cl.trade_day_count+'~', '~ACT+1~','ACTUAL'),'~ACT~', 'ACTUAL'),'~','')`

Answer (score 2):

Working answer from Alex K. comment:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(cl.trade_day_count, 'ACT','ACTUAL'),'ACTUAL+1', 'ACTUAL')
```

Comment: This would replace ACT+1 -> ACTUAL+1 but I think he wants ACTUAL on its own & has an overlap problem

Comment: `REPLACE(REPLACE(cl.trade_day_count, 'ACT','ACTUAL'),'ACT+1', 'ACTUAL')` seems to work fine for ACT or ACT+1 values.

Comment: @fercstar Regarding edit: How do you know they don't want all other values to be null?  the else wasn't in the original question.  maybe when it's CR they only want ACT and ACT+1 values but displayed with Actual?

Comment: the inner `ACT` to `ACTUAL` makes `ACT+1` into `ACTUAL+1` which does not match the next `ACT+1` replace, `REPLACE(REPLACE(cl.trade_day_count, 'ACT','ACTUAL'),'ACTUAL+1', 'ACTUAL')` would work I think.

Comment: @alexK you're right.  I even wrote a demo and misread the results!

Comment: I don't have a DB to test it I thought it would only replace exact matches without the wildcard  like :   'ACT%', 'ACTUAL'

Comment: You'd have to use an arbitrary value not in the cl.trade_day_count column and  set each value to it then covert those to ACTUAL `Replace(REPLACE(REPLACE(cl.trade_day_count, 'ACT+1','~Fixme~'),'ACT', '~Fixme~'),'~Fixme~','ACTUAL')` http://rextester.com/WUDGB33936

Comment: @fercstar's edited it again I think that will cover both correct xQbert?

Comment: @scath Yes/No if the trade_Day_count can contain 'ACTUAL' as a value  (or anything with just ACT) then you'd get ACTUALUAL)